# Which front end technology I use with drupal 8 backend?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

One of my client wants to integrate drupal 8 as a backend development and they asking for which framework is good for the front end Development.

As per my understanding, I Suggested React JS for Front-End Development. So Whats your Suggestions for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say that but it actually depends of what you need to do. 
If you need a Headless drupal, yeah i guess reactjs is a good idea, but if you dont, you need to know that Drupal 8 has by default a pretty good Front-end workflow with Twig templates (front-end without php), and you also got many good themes including useful tools such as gulp, browser sync, bower, and so on. Personnaly, I would recommand you to start with [Radix theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/radix).

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, May I Know Any Drupal 8 Webinars which are coming in this month so I Can understand Easily.